# Log rotation with Qt Framework

Tags: c++, qt, logging

I need to implement one log rotation system for my applicaton in linux with the following constraints:

1. Avoid >=5MB files. When logfile reach 5MB, create a new file.
2. Only keep the 20 newer files

I'm have been looking in Qt documentation in order to try it without use unix **logrotate** command, only using Qt framework, but no luck at this point. Any way to do that? Is this implemented in Qt?

Comment: I haven't found any so I implemented small one myself using QFile, but I needed to rotate within one file, which you can do same but appending and creating new.

Comment: qInstallMessageHandler and a bit of programming? We did so.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I know that, but I'm looking for one qt API to do without need to write myself all the code.

Comment: There is no predefined API in Qt for log rotation. You may implement your own logic or use any of existing logging framework with Qt.

Comment: "need to write myself all the code" All 50 lines of it? If you think it's complicated, you're doing it wrong. There's no Qt api, but it's a problem that's trivial to solve. Just give it a try.